# How to fix warning caused by Flow Function Types using eslint-plugin-react?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, flowtype

I'm getting a warning on the following line on my react component

```
handleToggle: Function;
```

I'm using [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) and [Flow](https://flow.org/) and I'm getting a warning "handleToggle should be placed after constructor". This is related to rule react/sort-comp. I tried with the following on my .eslintrc.json

```
 "react/sort-comp": [1, {
  "order": [
    "static-methods",
    "lifecycle",
    "everything-else",
    "render"
  ],
  "groups": {
    "lifecycle": [
      "displayName",
      "propTypes",
      "contextTypes",
      "childContextTypes",
      "/^.*: Function$/",
      "mixins",
      "statics",
      "defaultProps",
      "state",
      "constructor",
      "getDefaultProps",
      "getInitialState",
      "getChildContext",
      "componentWillMount",
      "componentDidMount",
      "componentWillReceiveProps",
      "shouldComponentUpdate",
      "componentWillUpdate",
      "componentDidUpdate",
      "componentWillUnmount"
    ]
  }
}]
```

But I'm unable to fix the warning. I want the Function Types before constructor the same as the other Type Definition. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It would help if you included a code snippet that illustrates how you want your code to be organized, and exhibits the undesirable warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `eslint-plugin-react` is not aware of Flow, so there is no group for "type definitions". You can make eslint let you place your type definitions at the beginning of your component by moving `"everything-else"` to the top of your component (before `"static-methods"`, but that will also allow you to define any functions or instance variables (in case you're using them) before the `constructor`.

ie, change your `.eslintrc.json` to:

```
 "react/sort-comp": [1, {
  "order": [
    "everything-else",
    "static-methods",
    "lifecycle",
    "render"
  ],
  "groups": { /* ... */ }
 }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried this but I want the flow type definition before the constructor but the actual function below. If I do this I have to put both before the constructor, and that is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: In that case, what you want to do is not possible unless `eslint-plugin-react` gets updated with Flow support. As it stands, this plugin is not aware of type annotations, and for that reason cannot behave as you would like it to.

Answer (score 2):

you can now add a "new" item (`type-annotations`)* to the order section in the config:

```
"react/sort-comp": [
  2,
  {
    "order": [
      "type-annotations",  // <-- this is "new"
      "static-methods",
      "lifecycle",
      "everything-else",
      "render"
    ],
    "groups": {
      "lifecycle": [
        "displayName",
        "propTypes",
        "contextTypes",
        "childContextTypes",
        "mixins",
        "statics",
        "defaultProps",
        "constructor",
        "getDefaultProps",
        "state",
        "getInitialState",
        "getChildContext",
        "getDerivedStateFromProps",
        "componentWillMount",
        "UNSAFE_componentWillMount",
        "componentDidMount",
        "componentWillReceiveProps",
        "UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps",
        "shouldComponentUpdate",
        "componentWillUpdate",
        "UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate",
        "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate",
        "componentDidUpdate",
        "componentDidCatch",
        "componentWillUnmount"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

after this, eslint will stop complaining.

`*` found here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/sort-comp.md#rule-options